# Remove base url for one link in CodeIgniter site

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink

CodeIgniter Question.  I want to add an external link to one of my CI sites, so I don't want to have the base URL included.  No matter what I do, I always get something like this: `http://www.ourwayproj.net/index.php/www.yahoo.com`.  when all I want is this: `http://www.yahoo.com`.  How do I remove the base url from this one link that I want to add?

here is the tag I want to use: `<a target="_blank" href=<?=$account->getUrl().".webbiz.biz";?>><img alt="moores78 (9K)" src="moores78.jpg" height="240" width="240" /></a>`

Comment: it should work as long as $account->getUrl() it an absolute address (starts with http://)

Comment: No, the "$account->getUrl()" function will only give me the ip ie: "yahoo" portion of the url

Comment: the link needs the protocol prepended to it - http://

Comment: Got - thank you.  For those who my run into the same issue here is how the url should look: <a target = "_blank" href = <?="http://".$account->getUrl().".webbiz.biz";?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Pretty answer from comments*;

For an external link, the address needs to be prepended with the protocol, e.g **http://**

```
<a target = "_blank" href = <?="http://".$account->getUrl().".webbiz.biz";?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did that in my project and use:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $row->ip_address; ?>" target="_blank">Show</a>
```

and it will produce an IP Address stored at my database

```
http://172.xx.xx.xx
```